# How to connect VirtualBox to internet using USB modem

Tags: virtualbox, wireless, usb-drive

I'm trying to use VirtualBox to emulate an android device. But I need to be connected to the internet so that I can use the IP address of the virtual machine I created inside VirtualBox to connect with Eclipse (adb).

However, since I'm using a USB modem, the wireless connection does not appear when I choose using Bridged Adopter. The only enlisted connection is the Local Area Connection. I've tried the following, but to no avail:

1. Use NAT instead of Bridged Adopter
2. Try sharing the connection with VirtualBox. I couldn't share since the Sharing tab is missing in Network Connection Properties (I tried several options to enable Sharing tab, but to no avail too. I'm using Windows 7 Starter Edition).
3. Try turning off the firewall entirely in order to be sure that nothing is being blocked.

So, is there another way to connect VirtualBox to internet using USB modem without sharing the connection? If no, how can I enable the Sharing Tab?

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

it's not necessary to share your modem connection, just create one VirtualBox Host Only Adapter and configure it to DHCP mode.
you've done right use NAT for the VirtualBox Network Configuration.
just connect your USB Modem so your VirtualBox is now connected to internet.
I've just try it brother.
it's my configuration, check the link below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/solc8sx9gtrawl4/Snapshot_2013-12-07_131209.png